# How can I replace icons of an application's executable?

Tags: windows, shell, icons, binary-files

I have an application whose executable contains some default icon. Now, I know I can use a shortcut with whatever icon I want, but what I'm looking to do is change the icon without the executable itself. How can I do this?

**Notes**:

- Using Windows 7 64bit, but I'm interested in 32-bit executables as well, which will perhaps run on Win XP etc.
- Keeping the same filesize is a plus, but not necessary.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched how to do this? What version of Windows are you using? What do you mean "change the icon without the executable itself"?

Comment: He woulds like to edit the .exe file and change the icon contained in that file. This icon is called a program resource. You could read up on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673203/add-icon-to-existing-exe-file-from-the-command-line

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829736/windows-changing-the-name-icon-of-an-application-associated-with-a-file-type

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

It allows to change the resources within exe files - including images.

Alternatively, since Resource Hacker is no longer being developed, there is another tool with similar capabilities - [Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm).

Edit:
This one as well: [reseditor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/)

Edit2: There's more. [Resedit](http://www.resedit.net/)

Comment: I succeeded using Resource Hacker, but I wish you could expand your answer some, describing what needs to be done with it, the fact that I want to replace Icon Groups rather than just Icons etc.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
Right click on your .exe 
Property
```

[image]

Comment: See the arrow over the application icon? This is a shortcut, not the application itself. The question already stated that the shortcut icon can be changed.

Comment: Indeed, this does not apply to actual executables.