# How to replace icon in executable file?

Tags: windows-7, resources

I'm aware of this answer: [How can I replace icons of an application's executable?](https://superuser.com/q/687913/177510)

And that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14370553/261217

I've tried Resource Hacker, Resource Hacker FX, XN Resource Editor and several other resource editors I cannot even remember. They all are discontinued for now and they all produced broken exe file. No matter whether I use a new icon or edit an embedded one. Is there any modern tool I can use for this task, which will not produce broken exe? I'm looking for solution for Windows 7 x64, for 32-bit application.

And here is my exe: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cr3fm1yl5ukfc7c/KeysRemapper.exe?dl=0. I'm trying to replace the second icon (green letter S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is packed using [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/), an executable compressor.

You might want to [unpack it first](https://web.archive.org/web/20140216095431/http://dev-4story.wikispaces.com/Unpacking+UPX) and then try resource editing tools like [Resource Hacker FX](http://rammichael.com/resource-hacker-fx), [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) or [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/), etc.

You can unpack the executable (if it's not obfuscated) using the following command:

```
upx -d -o unpacked_filename.exe input_filename.exe
```

I've tried this, and it worked for me:

1. Replacing the icon resource on the unpacked EXE:
   [image: UPX unpacked EXE editing using Resource Hacker FX]
2. The result:

[image: Icon resource replaced]

Comment: For good measure, pack the executable again after you've replaced the icon resource.

Comment: I'm just curious, how did you know it was packed with UPX?

Comment: Great thanks, I will check out this solution soon.

Comment: @Raystafarian I downloaded the EXE and ran [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) on it. It detected that the EXE was UPX packed and asked me if I wanted to unpack it. I said yes. However, I wouldn't recommend using Universal Extractor as it's quite old now and there's a more useful fork of the program with the latest binaries of the unpacker software it uses (e.g. 7-zip, PeaZip, etc.) but I can't remember the name of the program.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [PEiD](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) to check whether the EXE is packed or not. Another way to do this is to [scan the file using VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5ca455c3af274391a28156c86560be177377fe723b508abe225fa05878edaca7/analysis/1412325579/) and see if an antivirus program detects that the executable is packed or not.

Comment: But by far, the easiest way to detect the presence of UPX is to open the file using a hex editor and doing a search for `UPX` (this won't work if the executable was intentionally obfuscated after compression).

Comment: I just found the [Universal Extractor fork](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=20420&start=440) if anyone's interested. I haven't tested it thoroughly so use it at your own risk

Comment: It seems like EXE is protected against unpacking. When I try to run unpacked version, it says "EXE corrupted" and finishes. It is not the message from the system, but from EXE itself.

Comment: @Mikhail The EXE is actually a [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that was compiled to EXE, so you can use [EXE2AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/Exe2Ahk.exe) on the original, packed executable to get the AutoHotkey AHK script and [compile it yourself with an icon of your choosing](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm).

Comment: To change the EXE's icon that's shown on the desktop, compile it with Ahk2Exe (not using the right-click context menu). You'll find `AHK2EXE` in `Program Files Directory\AutoHotkey\Compiler`. Make sure you specify your custom icon while compiling the script.

Comment: @Vinayak Yes, I wrote this script myself :) But there are two icons, displaying in system tray: one default, and one when script is suspended. With AHK2EXE I can only specify the default icon. There are solutions to set another icon for suspended state on AHK forums, but none of them worked for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17614/discussion-between-mikhail-and-vinayak).